# Unable to display image with React Native with uri

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm tinkering with React Native and am trying to simply display an image with the image library from a URL. When I run this, all that is shown is the 'React Native' text, but no image. What am I doing wrong?

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;

var AwesomeProject = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          React Native
        </Text>
        <Image 
          source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try giving the image component a height and width value.

```
<Image style= {{ height:50, width: 50 }} >
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't do anything for me. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: OK, I think this did work after all. I accidentally destroyed my app when trying to rename it and started over. In the new app, adding the h and w was the difference between this working and not.

Comment: it also need to be served over https from iOS 8 or add an exception: https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/

Comment: Is there another approach without using `height` and `width` as I want the image to be displayed in full screen?

Comment: Raj, you could use the Dimensions, Get the window width and assign it to the image width variable, height can be anything you choose.
Dimensions.get('window');

Answer (score 1):

```
flex: 1,
width: null,
height: null,
resizeMode: 'cover',
```

This style will make image flexible and cover the whole container

Answer (score 1):

In iOS you are unable to receive http requests, only https. Try adding this to your **info.plist** file in xcode (make sure it is in this order exactly):

```html
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 1):

when we use an image in react-native the image will not expand to fill the space available to it by default instead we have to add style rule that how big the image should be.if your not add style for image with height and width you cant appear the image